# How can I make my bot counting how many time a user has a role?

Tags: javascript, scripting, discord, discord.js

I want to make a bot with discord.js v12 to count how many time a user has a role and then send it  in a channel with a webhook. My problem is how to make it counting time. Here is my code:

```
if(command === 'on') {
        const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'On Duty')
        message.author.send('You are on duty')
        message.member.roles.add(role)
        message.react('<:tick:902920026489749564>')
    } else if(command == 'off'){
    const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'On Duty')
    message.member.roles.remove(role)
    let seconds = Math.floor(message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id) / 1000);
    let minutes = Math.floor(message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id) / 60);
    let hours = Math.floor(message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id) / 60);
    let days = Math.floor(message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id) / 24);

    seconds %= 60;
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 24;

    const wc = new WebhookClient('MyWebhookId', 'myWebhookUrl')
    const log = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('DUTY LOGS')
    .setDescription(`Username: <@${message.author.id}>\n`
    + `Days: **${days}**\n`
    + `Hours: **${hours}**\n`
    + `Minutes: **${minutes}**\n`
    + `Seconds: **${seconds}**`)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor('#fa0505')
    wc.send({
        username : message.author.tag,
        avatarURL : message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic : true }),
        embeds : [log]
    })
    message.react('<:tick:902920026489749564>')
}
```

[It gives me that answer when I type !off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDQXm.jpg)

Comment: `I want to make a bot with discord.js v12 to count how many time a user has a role` - a user can only have a role once... did you mean how many members have a role? Did you mean how much time in between when they got it and when it was taken away? I don't understand

Comment: Also `GuildMemberRoleManager.has` returns a boolean, and you are dividing it by 1000 and `true / 1000` is actually `1 / 1000` which is `0.001` which rounds down to 0 and `false / 1000` is actually `0 / 1000` which is `0` ... the answer is always 0 since `true / 24` is `0.042`

Comment: @MrMythical I assume they are trying to check how much time has passed since user got the role

Comment: Ok, well the bot will either need to be on **almost all the time** for it to be accurate, or use a db to set the date linked to a user, then check the current date and subtract the linked date